# Исполнитель "Робот". Задача про закрашивание клеток - рандомные несрабатывания кода

Tags: python

Всем привет. Программирование я изучаю буквально пару дней, поэтому очень прошу тапками не бросаться, в поиске подобного не нашел.
Задача: Закрасить клетки. Расстояние до стены неизвестно.
[image: Изображение задачи]
Это Оператор "Робот", думаю многие с ним встречались в самом начале пути. По каким-то причинам в последней клетке, где он должен остановиться, ибо условие while более не выполняется, он иногда все же крашится в стену. **Иногда** - ключевое слово. Проверочная программа выдает 5 рандомизированных условий одной и той же задачи и иногда мой код их проходит успешно, а иногда - нет - робот крашится в стену по неизвестным причинам. С чем связано - ума не приложу, голову сломал, plz help.

```
@task
def task_8_10():
    while not wall_is_on_the_right():
        if wall_is_above() and wall_is_beneath():
            move_right()
        if not wall_is_above() and wall_is_beneath():
            move_up()
            fill_cell()
            move_down()
            move_right()
        if not wall_is_beneath() and wall_is_above():
            move_down()
            fill_cell()
            move_up()
            move_right()
        if not wall_is_beneath() and not wall_is_above():
            move_down()
            fill_cell()
            move_up(2)
            fill_cell()
            move_down()
            move_right()
    else:
        if not wall_is_beneath() and not wall_is_above():
        move_down()
        fill_cell()
        move_up(2)
        fill_cell()
        move_down()
        if not wall_is_above() and wall_is_beneath():
        move_up()
        fill_cell()
        move_down()
        if not wall_is_beneath() and wall_is_above():
        move_down()
        fill_cell()
        move_up()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> if wall_is_above() and wall_is_beneath():
> ```

Возможно ли это, чтобы *одновременно* стена была над и под?

---

> ```
>     if wall_is_above() and wall_is_beneath():
>         move_right()
>     if not wall_is_above() and wall_is_beneath():
>         move_up()
>         fill_cell()
>         move_down()
>         move_right()
>     if not wall_is_beneath() and wall_is_above():
>         move_down()
>         fill_cell()
>         move_up()
>         move_right()
>     if not wall_is_beneath() and not wall_is_above():
>         move_down()
>         fill_cell()
>         move_up(2)
>         fill_cell()
>         move_down()
>         move_right()
> ```

Может быть, что лучше бы было `elif`:

```
    if wall_is_above() or wall_is_beneath():
        move_right()
    elif not wall_is_above() and wall_is_beneath():
        move_up()
        fill_cell()
        move_down()
        move_right()
    elif not wall_is_beneath() and wall_is_above():
        move_down()
        fill_cell()
        move_up()
        move_right()
    elif not wall_is_beneath() and not wall_is_above():
        move_down()
        fill_cell()
        move_up(2)
        fill_cell()
        move_down()
        move_right()
```

чтобы не делать в одном шаге цикла `while` более, чем нужно.

Comment: Да, стены одновременно над и под - возможно, как на примере, который я приложил картинкой - в столбцах 2, 7, 8 итд

Заменил в вашем коде с `elif` `or` на `and` (в случае с `or` робот просто скипает закрашивание клеток там, где стена только сверху или снизу) и всё заработало.

Объясните пожалуйста - хочу разобраться как именно всё починилось. Чем код с `elif` кардинально отличается от множества условий `if`? Насколько мне известно - ничем кроме удобства, краткости и лучшей читаемости кода, но видимо я ошибаюсь.